# MEncoder conversion - broken frames

Tags: linux, video, mencoder

When I'm converting files from mp4 to other formats like flv or mp4 (for mobile), for some files I get output files broken, containing broken frames (pixelated or completely grey). Some frames are OK but most of them are broken.

Here are the command used and some log errors:

```
 Command:
=========================================================
/usr/local/bin/mencoder /home/msdemo/public_html/media/files_video/user9/11611ef5b5.mp4 -o /home/msdemo/public_html/media/files_flv/user9/11611ef5b5_ipod.mp4 -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=1500:nocabac:vbv_maxrate=1500:vbv_bufsize=2000:level_idc=30:global_header:frameref=2:mixed_refs:me=umh:subq=6:partitions=all:threads=auto -af resample=44100:0:0,volnorm=1:0.25 -oac faac -faacopts mpeg=4:object=2:raw:br=128 -of lavf -lavfopts i_certify_that_my_video_stream_does_not_use_b_frames -ofps 25.000 -vf scale=640:368,harddup -demuxer lavf 2>&1

Output:
MEncoder 1.0rc1-4.1.2 (C) 2000-2006 MPlayer Team
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3460  @ 2.80GHz (Family: 6, Model: 30, Stepping: 5)
CPUflags: Type: 6 MMX: 1 MMX2: 1 3DNow: 0 3DNow2: 0 SSE: 1 SSE2: 1
Compiled for x86 CPU with extensions: MMX MMX2 SSE SSE2

get_path("config") problem
success: format: 0  data: 0x0 - 0x2c0b52d
libavformat file format detected.
VIDEO:  [avc1]  1016x572  24bpp  25.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
[V] filefmt:35  fourcc:0x31637661  size:1016x572  fps:25.00  ftime:=0.0400
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [faad] AAC (MPEG2/4 Advanced Audio Coding)
FAAD: compressed input bitrate missing, assuming 128kbit/s!
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 128.0 kbit/9.07% (ratio: 16000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [faad] afm: faad (FAAD AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio) decoder)
==========================================================================
** MUXER_LAVF *****************************************************************
You have certified that your video stream does not contain B frames.
REMEMBER: MEncoder's libavformat muxing is presently broken and will generate
INCORRECT files in the presence of B frames. Moreover, due to bugs MPlayer
will play these INCORRECT files as if nothing were wrong!
*******************************************************************************
OK, exit
Opening video filter: [expand osd=1]
Expand: -1 x -1, -1 ; -1, osd: 1, aspect: 0.000000, round: 1
Opening video filter: [harddup]
Opening video filter: [scale w=640 h=368]
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
VDec: vo config request - 1016 x 572 (preferred colorspace: Planar YV12)
VDec: using Planar I420 as output csp (no 1)
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
SwScaler: reducing / aligning filtersize 8 -> 8
SwScaler: reducing / aligning filtersize 8 -> 8
SwScaler: reducing / aligning filtersize 8 -> 7
SwScaler: reducing / aligning filtersize 8 -> 7

SwScaler: BICUBIC scaler, from yuv420p to yuv420p using MMX2
SwScaler: using 8-tap MMX scaler for horizontal luminance scaling
SwScaler: using 8-tap MMX scaler for horizontal chrominance scaling
SwScaler: using n-tap MMX scaler for vertical scaling (YV12 like)
SwScaler: 1016x572 -> 640x368
x264 [info]: using SAR=653/640
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 PHADD SSE4 Cache64
New_Face failed. Maybe the font path is wrong.
Please supply the text font file (~/.mplayer/subfont.ttf).
subtitle font: load_sub_face failed.
Pos:   0.0s      1f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.000 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s      2f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:-0.003 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s      3f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.001 [0:0]
1 duplicate frame(s)!
Pos:   0.0s      4f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.005 [0:0]
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]abs_diff_pic_num overflow
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]concealing 2304 DC, 2304 AC, 2304 MV errors
Pos:   0.0s      5f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.001 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s      6f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.005 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s      7f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.009 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s      8f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.013 [0:0]
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]abs_diff_pic_num overflow
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]concealing 2304 DC, 2304 AC, 2304 MV errors
Pos:   0.0s      9f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.009 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s     10f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.013 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s     11f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.017 [0:0]
Pos:   0.0s     12f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.021 [0:0]
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]abs_diff_pic_num overflow
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]concealing 2304 DC, 2304 AC, 2304 MV errors
VIDEO CODEC ID: 28
AUDIO CODEC ID: 15002, TAG: 0
Writing header...
Pos:   0.0s     13f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   2mb  A-V:0.017 [0:0]
Pos:   0.1s     14f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   2mb  A-V:0.021 [0:0]
Pos:   0.1s     15f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   2mb  A-V:0.025 [0:0]
Pos:   0.2s     16f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   3mb  A-V:0.029 [0:0]
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]abs_diff_pic_num overflow
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]concealing 2304 DC, 2304 AC, 2304 MV errors
Pos:   0.2s     17f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   3mb  A-V:0.025 [0:0]
Pos:   0.2s     18f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   5mb  A-V:0.027 [0:0]
Pos:   0.3s     19f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   7mb  A-V:0.031 [0:0]
Pos:   0.3s     20f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   9mb  A-V:0.035 [0:0]
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]abs_diff_pic_num overflow
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x87cf698]concealing 2304 DC, 2304 AC, 2304 MV errors
Pos:   0.4s     21f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   9mb  A-V:0.031 [0:0]
Pos:   0.4s     22f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   9mb  A-V:0.034 [0:0]
Pos:   0.4s     23f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   9mb  A-V:0.038 [0:0]
Pos:   0.5s     24f ( 0%)  0.00fps Trem:   0min   9mb  A-V:0.042 [0:0]
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: The command that you're using to perform this conversion includes some very strange options, and is in fact triggering a HUGE LOUD WARNING about what's wrong (prefixed with "MUXER_LAVF"). Where did you get this command from?

Comment: Why did you use the [tag:ffmpeg] tag when it appears you are using `mencoder`?

Comment: @duskwuff the command is from a video sharing script that I use... and I'm trying to fix this conversion problem. I will try to remove some parameters and test again. Thank you!

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, yes, you are right, changed tags form FFMpeg to MEncoder. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The version of mencoder you're using (1.0rc1) is **INCREDIBLY** old — it was an early development release from around 2006. The development team has fixed a lot of bugs since then, which most likely includes ones which were responsible for the issues you're seeing, as well as some which may compromise your system security. Update to a more recent version immediately.

Comment: I will do it. Thank you!